# How can I change the value on "require a password on wakeup" to false programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

How can I change the value on "require a password on wakeup" to false in power options programmatically
using C#. Currently it requires a password to unlock the computer when it wakes from sleep

by manual: power options-> advanced settings->
balanced-> require a password on wakeup -> on battery:yes
                                           plugged in:yes

Comment: Reellaborate your question, as the info u provided seems insufficient!

Comment: Regardless of context this seems very much like something that _should not be possible_ for security/privacy reasons

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is by [modifying the registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx):

In the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop` registry key, change the value of `ScreenSaverIsSecure` to `0`.

(According to [KB 928717](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928717/en-us), that's the correct registry key for modifying the "Require a password on wakeup" option.)

Answer (score 1):

Generally [you should use SystemParametersInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/search/searchresults.aspx?q=systemparametersinfo%20registry&sections=2905) where available instead of changing the registry yourself.

Perhaps [SystemParametersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `SPI_SETSCREENSAVESECURE` parameter does what you want. It exists only on Vista or later. I haven't tried it myself, but from the description it might be what you want.